# How can I set two sizes using Tableau tree map

Tags: tableau-api

A tree map can consist of the larger boxes and inside differing sizes of smaller boxes. Nothing I do in the shelf allows me to set two different measures sizes. I want my larger boxes to be proportional to my Total Population and the smaller boxes inside each to be proportional to my Utilization %. The three images I attached are my visualizations as well as one I found online that does exactly what I am trying to do.
[image: My Visual]

[image: What I am trying to do]

[image: My data]

Comment: Having checked the following link, I believe adding a second (third, forth etc.) dimension should nest further down while retaining the structure you require. What's the pill format of your first dimension? Are you able to attach a sample workbook? https://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2015/02/10/show-treemaps/

Comment: Here is a sample workbook. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvfZkiD4VF4CdLJEbcK5DDU6vBU

Comment: Please attach a .twbx workbook that has your data embedded.

Comment: What is the best way to do that? I am on my work computer and most file sharing sites are blocked. I do not see a way to directly attach.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvfZkiD4VF4CdWd1a6WEMpnJ29g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tableau, you can only use one set of size per sheet.